# Romulan ambassador Nanclus

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, romulan, the-undiscovered-country

In the *Star Trek: The Undiscovered Country*, what role did Ambassador Nanclus play in the conspiracy?

Did he act to prevent the Klingons and the Federation from forming an alliance?

Comment: Other than voting to have Kirk/McCoy extradited to Qonos, I don't recall him having a role. But he WAS named as a conspirator, so it's a good question.

Comment: @Omegacron: And one has to wonder how he, as a Romulan ambassador, could possibly have any say about whether or not to extradite UFP citizens to the Klingon Empire, anyway.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - very true. However, had he dissented it's likely that the UFP President would have refused to extradite them. During the scene in the President's office, he was basically the swing-vote. Not so much an official vote, but definitely an unofficial one.

Comment: Assassination of a treaty ambassador would likely fall under some type of joint jurisdiction, or atleast require some type of consensus of the member parties

Comment: Romulan and Klingons were official allies at the time after all, no?

Comment: That's a problem I always had with that movie.  It was supposed to be a big reveal during the mind meld scene, but I couldn't remember who the guy was.  So much so that I thought they said, "Romulan.. Ambassador.. Obnoxious" even after some re-watches on VHS.  I was 11 at the time, granted, but even looking back his role was never made all that clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He was at the least a conspirator

> In that year, he was involved in a conspiracy to sabotage peace talks
>   between the Federation and the Klingon Empire. While in a meeting with
>   the Federation President after the arrest of James Kirk and Leonard
>   McCoy, Nanclus lent his support to "Operation Retrieve," the proposal
>   to infiltrate Klingon space and rescue the hostages, put forth by
>   Nanclus' fellow conspirator, Colonel West. Later, Nanclus attended the
>   Khitomer Conference. After the crew of the USS Enterprise-A learned of
>   his involvement in the conspiracy, and successfully prevented the
>   assassination of the Federation President at the conference, he was
>   detained by Starfleet. (Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country)

[Nanclus-Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Nanclus)

Anywhere that you look on Memory Alpha they all say that he was a co-conspirator to undermine peace talks, so whether or not he was involved in the rest of what was going on, I am sure that he was at the least trying to undermine the peace talks and this gave him some ammunition

David A. McIntee once proposed that he may have been the initiator of the conspiracy in a Star Trek Magazine article

> Author David A. McIntee once proposed that Nanclus was actually the initiator of the conspiracy, having secretly put the idea that the Federation were the true threat to the Klingon Empire into General Chang's mind, due to Romulan concerns that the Klingons and Federation were about to form a pact. McIntee went on to characterize Nanclus as "almost certainly the true villain of the movie, and probably the most forgotten of the Trek villains." ([Star Trek Magazine issue 149](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Magazine_issue_149), p. 64)

[Nanclus, Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Nanclus)

Obviously the Romulans didn't want the Klingons and the Federation teaming up, because the Romulans couldn't possibly overpower them in tandem, which means that the Romulans could never expand into Federation or Klingon space.

Comment: At what point does being an instigator cause someone to become a conspirator? What about conspiracy theorists? Or even just a paranoid or concerned third party.

Comment: Down vote because Mcintee has nothing to do with the writing or production of the movie or anything to do with this character aside from a magazine conjecture

Comment: @cde, had you followed the links you would see that it is common knowledge --> [Memory Alpha - Nanclus](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Nanclus). `While in a meeting with the Federation President after the arrest of James Kirk and Leonard McCoy, Nanclus lent his support to "Operation Retrieve," the proposal to infiltrate Klingon space and rescue the hostages, put forth by Nanclus' fellow conspirator, Colonel West.`

Comment: The Star Trek Magazine is an official magazine, so should be considered somewhat canon.  [Star Trek Magazine - Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Magazine)

Comment: also see (Memory Alpha - David McIntee)[http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/David_A._McIntee]. this makes it sound like he wrote an episode guide for Voyager and that he would have had another published but was thrown out because of publisher rivalry. so maybe he has some knowledge on the subject, at least enough to get published in an official magazine and an episode guide for a major Star Trek series that is in canon

Comment: The difference between was a conspirator and initiator is a very big difference